# MongoDB's Geo Queries - centerSphere gives no matches

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial

I specified a query that should give me all inserts in a specific circle. This is my Java code:

```html
....

DBCollection collRadius = mongo.getMyDB().getCollection(theCollectionName);

    List circle = new ArrayList();
    circle.add(new double[] { theLongitude, theLatitude });
    circle.add(theRaduisInMeters);
    BasicDBObject query =
        new BasicDBObject("geoposition", new BasicDBObject("$within", new      BasicDBObject("$centerSphere", circle)));
    List<DBObject> dbObList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();

    for (final DBObject venue : collRadius.find(query).toArray()) {
      dbObList.add(venue);
    }

    return dbObList;
  }
```

I specified a geo-spatial index for the DBObject "geoposition":

```html
    coll.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("geoposition", "2dsphere"));

BasicDBObject jts = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBList l = new BasicDBList();
    l.add(theGeoposition.y);
    l.add(theGeoposition.x);

    jts.put("geoposition", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("type", "Point").add("coordinate", l)
        .get());
```

My test function is just very simple and I am adding 3x the same Coordinate (JTS format):

```html
new Coordinate(
            52.417612999999998,
            9.637832999999999)
```

The I am checking the query with the following parameters: longitude: 9.637832999999998, latitude: 52.417612999999997 and radius (10. /  6371).
I can't find the reason, why the query always gives me no match. I changed $within to $geoWithin, I checked the correct value of longitude, latitude (Coordinate of JTS vs. MongoDB's notation). Any idea?

Best,

Tron

Comment: Any idea why MongoDB seem sto have a problem with that query? Is there any possibility to extract any debug information? As you can see, I am using java driver. MongoException is not capable to print out any debug information for that query. In cases of inserts, you can use WRITECONCERN.SAFE. The problem is, that the query does not lead to any result, except {}.

Comment: I found the reason..I only had to change "coordinate" to "coordinates" (I thought this key would just be a user-defined name for a field)